# Why my terminal is not allowing to use pip?? But allowing pip3

Tags: python, pandas, sublimetext3

I was trying to install pandas and using "pip install pandas"
But my Terminal was not allowing me to use pip.

When I tried pip3 instead of pip, pandas download was completed.

Although, my problem was not solved as I am still not able to import pandas in my SUBLIMEText3.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Learn about paths and system environment variables from YouTube, blogs, books or Google and I guarantee you'll find an answer for your question and learn some new stuff too, And can you provide what errors are you seeing when trying to import pandas?

Comment: ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: My problem is I am using Python 2.7, so I am supposed to use pip, not pip3. Correct? I feel Pandas is not installed in my Python 2.7, which might be installed in Python 3.0. But I am using 2.7, so Sublime text 3.0 is not able to access the Pandas file

Comment: When you type python in you terminal what is the version you see?

Comment: Now, I googled and tried:
1. python --version: showing 2.7.16

                 2. also tried python3 --version: showing 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to install pandas or other packages in python2 write this in your terminal:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

And for python3 write this in your terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install pandas
```

Comment: I used python -m pip install pandas

Showing: No module named pip

Comment: I used this in my sublime text : import sys.     print(sys.version)

Which shows that the default Python is 2.7.16

Comment: Then the error is happening because of a failure in the installation in python2 I suggest you reinstall it.

Comment: As the higher version is already there, so system might not allow me to install any module in lower version. This looks like the possible reason.

Comment: No I and alot of people have both python2 and python3 installed so its not the problem, The problem is with the installation of python2 as pip2 in not in path.

Comment: I have no idea what is the issue with Python 2, which was pre-installed by Apple. Anyhow, I am happy that my problem is solved using Python3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing some points which helped me to find the answer.

pip install pandas was not allowed so I used pip3 install pandas to download.

I later checked in sublime Text3 which version of Python it is running using below:
import sys

print(sys.version)

The result shows: 2.7.16

So, I have changed the version to Python 3 using these steps: Tools-->Build System-->Python3

Now, I can see Pandas running

Although, I was not sure why terminal was not finding pip.

Comment: Mostly, I feel when I am having higher version I am supposed to download Pandas (or any other module) in higher version

Comment: That is correct. Python 2 and Python 3 are completely different versions of the language, and any modules you may have had installed under 2 will need to be reinstalled using `pip3`.